# Mapping cell range to a value

Tags: excel-2010

I have 2 columns of data. However the volume is quite large and I would like to classify this data in value range for each column.

I would like to create 5 categories of data range: 0 to 5, 6 to 10, 11 to 15, 16 to 20 and 21 or greater. These categories can then reside in column `C` and `D`. I would like to do this so that I can run some pivots. Is this the best way to categorise or is there any advanced functionality within pivots that i can use?

Thanks

```
A   B

25  0
23  0
24  5
185 4
46  33
26  14
17  1
17  1
55  11
6   0
6   5
13  6
34  4
45  7
24  5
112 42
35  -88
8   4
8   16
108 21
60  16
21  4
121 103
36  1
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create data ranges based on the values in column A? If so, you can just use a five-part IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in perfect shape to use with pivot tables. There is no need to break it up. In fact, spreading the data over several columns would make it more difficult to run pivot tables across it.

You can use the **Group** function in a pivot table to arrange data in 'buckets'.

[image]